# Can't play properly 1080 and 720 video files

Tags: amd-graphics, hd-video

I just got a second hand much faster computer then the one I had before and I am surprised that it has trouble to read 720pix or 1080HD videos with fluidity and even blocks almost completely on 1080HD movies.

It is an Asus X5DAB with 6GB RAM

and:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v] (rev ff)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you running 16.04?

Comment: Please install VLC, and download a 1080p video to test/see what happens. The Radeon HD 3200 should be able to play HD video with absolutely no issues. In addition, if you are running 16.04/16.10, you should downgrade to 14.04 in order to use the latest `fglrx` driver.

Comment: yes, I am using 16.04. Why should I downgrade be able to use a latest driver??? how should I do that? I had the login loophole with 14.04 and made a fresh new install from usb boot of 16.04.

Comment: and yes this is happening with vlc. the default movie player is actually doing better ...

Comment: Actually it is a HD 4570 graphics 512Mb as it is writen on a sticker on the computer.

Comment: still no help??